# WinForms button default style changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i'm writing a small winforms project. i've written a "main" formbox (self made controls eg) from which i derive my other forms. i've the problem that the default button design / style changed to an old "flat" design and not the new "3D-style" (since vista).

that's what i have

[image]

that's what it should be

[image]

i never changed the design manually so i realy don't know why this has happend. i've already searched for a solution in google and here but i belive i'm using the wrong words to search.

does somebody know how to change the design back to the new 3D-style or how to change the design globally ?

best regards alex

Comment: Please post the content of your program's `Main` (entrypoint) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the call to `Application.EnableVisualStyles` in your `Main` method, it should look like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main() {

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    using(MainForm form = new MainForm()) {
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the hate for .NET?

Comment: Why indeed. I LOVE .NET. :)