# Visual Studio VB winform style/theme changed? Texbox now has dropshadow?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, themes

I have a winform project I have been writing for 10 years.  I'm using VS2010.

Today the style of the buttons checkbox, groupbox and DGVborders have changed to a square dropshadow style.

In the IDE I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0be6K.jpg

When debugging or publish the style changed to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96EZY.jpg

I checked the Application.EnableVisualStyles per:
[WinForms button default style changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866260/winforms-button-default-style-changed)

I'm sure I accidentally changed a setting or codeline, but I can't seem to find where.
Any insight is appreciated

EDIT:
It almost looks like it has something to do with a Windows update?  Computers that have not been restarted do not have this issue.

Comment: Project Properties -> Application -> Enable XP visual styles (if you don't have a `Sub Main`, otherwise in the module where `Sub Main()` is).

Comment: Thanks Jim, I did have XP visual styles enabled and tried adding Application.EnableVisualStyles() to the startup as well.

Comment: What startup? VB.Net doesn't have a `Program.vb`, unless you make one disabling the Application FrameWork. Then you can start your program from a `Sub Main()`. Did you do this? You can't have both. A `Sub Main()` and the `Enable XP visual styles` option available. Which is it? If you have a `Sub Main()` in `Program.vb`, then you need to set both `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` and 
`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)` there, before you initialize `MainForm`.

Comment: Thanks again Jim, Sorry for the confusion.  I have a form named FORMstartup.vb that is the Startup form.  I do not have a Sub Main() in a module.  I tried to put Application.EnableVisualStyles()  in the FORMstart_Load, just to see if it would change anything and it did not.

Comment: It's too late at that point. That mode must be set in the entry point of your application, before any UI element is created. Before a Form's constructor is initialized. At run-time you could have used `Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled` (but this requires a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles`, you should know you have used this) or called [SetWindowTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) with the wrong parameters.